# Subquery in select statement returning SQL error

Tags: mysql

I get an SQL error for this query

> Error Number: 1064
>     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)
>    FROM `cast_gallery` q
>    JOIN `all_media` r on q.all_media_id=r.id
>    WHERE q.pa' at line 1

```
SELECT `cast_name`, `cast_slug`, (SELECT count(q.*)
 FROM `cast_gallery` q
 JOIN `all_media` r on q.all_media_id=r.id
 WHERE q.parent = `casts`.`id` AND r.approved=1) as image_gallery, `active`, `view`, `checked`, `sex`, `id`
FROM (`casts`)
ORDER BY `cast_name` asc
LIMIT 10
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count total number of rows, we use [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count), not `Count(q.*)`. Also, there is no need of parentheses around `casts` in the `From` clause.

```
SELECT `cast_name`, 
       `cast_slug`, 
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM `cast_gallery` q
        JOIN `all_media` r on q.all_media_id=r.id
        WHERE q.parent = `casts`.`id` AND 
              r.approved=1) as image_gallery, 
      `active`, 
      `view`, 
      `checked`, 
      `sex`, 
      `id`
FROM `casts`
ORDER BY `cast_name` asc
LIMIT 10
```

**Additional Info:**

`COUNT(...)` is used to count the number of **non-NULL** values; however `COUNT(*)` will count the total number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

try to just change  `count(q.*)` to `count(*)`

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax for count is incorrect. If we want to find out the number of rows in subquery we can use count(*). Please refer to http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_count.asp.html for more clarifiction.

```
SELECT `cast_name`, `cast_slug`, (SELECT count(*)
FROM `cast_gallery` q
JOIN `all_media` r on q.all_media_id=r.id
WHERE q.parent = `casts`.`id` AND r.approved=1) as image_gallery, `active`, 
`view`, `checked`, `sex`, `id`
FROM (`casts`)
ORDER BY `cast_name` asc
LIMIT 10
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

you can try instead of count(q.*), you can use q.all_media_id

```
SELECT `cast_name`, `cast_slug`, (SELECT count(q.all_media_id)
 FROM `cast_gallery` q
 JOIN `all_media` r on q.all_media_id=r.id
 WHERE q.parent = `casts`.`id` AND r.approved=1) as image_gallery, `active`, `view`, `checked`, `sex`, `id`
FROM (`casts`)
ORDER BY `cast_name` asc
LIMIT 10
```